# Where does Aristotle mention Aesop's fables?

Tags: aristotle

I have read most of Aesop's fables. (I liked some of them, though for more of the same with twice the punch, I prefer Sa'di's *Gulistan*.)

I have read the Poetics from cover to cover, but I don't remember the fables of Aesop being mentioned. Maybe I dozed off? I know for a fact that he does discuss that ancient text, but I'd like to know where.

Comment: I never knew this. Did they know each other personally, or was Aesop simply a well-known author by Aristotle's time?

Comment: Friends, no. Aesop seems to have been around when the Hittite empire disintegrated beyond all recognition, if memory serves. At any rate, he was ancient history for the classical Greeks.

Comment: Good question! Fyi - we're now doing [Descartes week](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/291/its-descartes-week) if you're interested in participating.

Answer (score 3):

Aesop is mentioned in the *Rhetoric* (2:20), *Meterology* (2:3), and *On the Parts of Animals* (3:2).

This is not a comprehensive list; there might be other references my casual search may have missed.

Comment: How does he mention Aesop? In reference to his stories (and how) or to him personally?

Comment: @Mitch - for example, in _Rhetoric_ (2:20) "Of the latter, again, there are two varieties, the illustrative parallel and the fable (e.g. the fables of Aesop, those from Libya)." - see http://rhetoric.eserver.org/aristotle/rhet2-20.html . or _Meteorology_ "Any one who thinks like Democritus that the sea is diminishing and will disappear in the end reminds us of Aesop's tales." (http://classics.mit.edu/Aristotle/meteorology.2.ii.html). Google is your friend.